# Code checker tells me my work is wrong but I am sure it's correct

Tags: html

Create a DIV with an attribute of `data-cc-digits`. It should contain four INPUT text fields, each with a size of 4 and a placeholder of ---- (4 dashes).

Code checker says: "You need to create the specified INPUT elements within the `data-cc-digits` DIV"

It does not specify if I should use `maxlength` or `minlength` to clamp the input.

```
<div data-cc-digits=""> 
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----">
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----">
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----">
      <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----">
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please learn how to [format your question correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so the code shows (you need 4 spaces before any code to be automatically displayed).  I would do it for you, but it wouldn't make your question any more understandable

Answer (score 0):

You should show more codes. But, it appears you will get the same error if your data-cc-digits inputs are wrong and if your data-cc-info inputs are wrong.

Try this:

```
 <div data-cc-digits>

   <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
   <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
   <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />
   <input type="text" size="4" placeholder="----" />

 </div>
 <div data-cc-info>

    <input type="text" size="20" placeholder="Name Surname" />
    <input type="text" size="6" placeholder="MM/YY" />

  </div>
```